# Python argparse errors with '%' in help string

Tags: python, string-formatting, argparse, percent-encoding

I have a default value that contains a '%' which I also insert in to the help doc of my argument. E.g.:

```
default = "5% foo"
animrender_group.add_argument(
    "--foo",
    default=default,
    help="Foo amount. Default: %s" % default,
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Argparse errors on parse_args()

```
[snip]
    args = parser.parse_args()
[snip]"../python2.5/site-packages/argparse.py", line 622, in _expand_help
    return self._get_help_string(action) % params
ValueError: unsupported format character 'O' (0x4f) at index 83
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had tried a traditional escape character, which did not work. Then I found a comment about using a '%' as an escape character and this worked. E.g.:

```
default = "5% foo"
foo_group.add_argument(
    "--foo",
    default=default,
    help="Foo amount. Default: %s" % default.replace(r"%", r"%%")),
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I'm glad I don't need to replace all '%' with '[percent sign]'. Hah.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to include defaults is with a `%(default)s` in the help line.

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--foo', default="5% foo", help="Foo amount. Default: %(default)s")
p.print_help()
```

which produces

```
usage: ipython [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   Foo amount. Default: 5% foo
```

From the `argparse` documentation:

> The help strings can include various format specifiers to avoid repetition of things like the program name or the argument default. The available specifiers include the program name, %(prog)s and most keyword arguments to add_argument(), e.g. %(default)s, %(type)s, etc.:

Comment: Awesome tip! Will it auto-escape '%'?

Comment: Note the `%` in my default value. There's no need to auto-escape because `argparse` doesn't try to 'evaluate' the default value.  Your code needed it because you put the default value in the help string before you gave it to `argparse`.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not have a default value and just want to have a percentage sign in the help message, add a another `%` to escape it:

```
import argparse
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--foo', help="Foo is always 100%%!")
p.print_help()
```

Which gives you:

```
usage: [-h] [--foo FOO]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   Foo is always 100%!
```